# What mechanism prevent Colchicum Autumnale from being affected by Colchicine

Tags: cell-division

Colchicine is a chemical usually used to cause polyploidy mutant by inhibiting chromosome segregation. 
It is synthesized in the Colchicum Autumnale. 
But what mechanism prevent C. Autumnale from being affected by the Colchicine?